# XMLHttpRequest - Immediately-invoked Function Expression

Tags: javascript

This may seem like a daft question but I want to check I'm on the right track.

I've written two versions of the XMLHttpRequest wrapper; which both work fine.

```js
const httpRequest = function () {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    return function ( config = { url: '', method: 'GET', onLoadStart: null, onLoad: null, onProgress: null, onError: null, onAbort: null, onLoadEnd: null, onTimeout: null, timeout : null }) {

        xhr.open(config.method, config.url);
        xhr.onloadstart = config.onLoadStart;
        xhr.onload = config.onLoad;
        xhr.onprogress = config.onProgress;
        xhr.onerror = config.onError;
        xhr.onabort = config.onAbort;
        xhr.onloadend = config.onLoadEnd;
        xhr.ontimeout = config.onTimeout;
        xhr.timeout = config.timeout;
        return xhr;
    };
}();
```

and this one

```js
function httpRequest(config = { url: '', method: 'GET', onLoadStart: null, onLoad: null, onProgress: null, onError: null, onAbort: null, onLoadEnd: null, onTimeout: null, timeout : null }) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open(config.method, config.url);
    xhr.onloadstart = config.onLoadStart;
    xhr.onload = config.onLoad;
    xhr.onprogress = config.onProgress;
    xhr.onerror = config.onError;
    xhr.onabort = config.onAbort;
    xhr.onloadend = config.onLoadEnd;
    xhr.ontimeout = config.onTimeout;
    xhr.timeout = config.timeout;

    return xhr;
}
```

I'm struggling to pinpoint why you would use an immediately-invoked Function Expression where a normal function works? Hoping someone can enlighten me as I've read for this kind of scenario an immediately invoked function is the better case.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an appropriate use of IIFE.

Comment: @Barmar - Are you able to expand on that at all, please.? There is a lot of confusing information around and I like to know what is an appropriate use for IIFE's. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the two methods is in when the `XMLHttpRequest` object is created.

With the first approach, you call it like this:

```
h = httpRequest();
xhr1 = h({ ... });
xhr1.send(...);
xhr2 = h({ ... });
xhr2.send(...);
```

Calling `httpRequest()` creates a single `XMLHttpRequest` object, which is assigned to both `xhr1` and `xhr2`.

This won't work well, because creating `xhr2` overwrites the properties of that `XMLHttpRequest` object. But if you can ensure that you don't call `h()` again until you've completed the previous use, it will save a little memory.

With the second approach, you just call `httpRequest()` directly, and it returns a new `XMLHttpRequest` object each time.

```
xhr1 = httpRequest({...});
xhr1.send(...);
xhr2 = httpRequest({...});
xhr2.send(...);
```

This is safe because you're not overwriting anything.

If you change the first version so that `let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();` is at the beginning of the inner function, then it will be equivalent to the second method, and just a little more verbose to use it.